# License plate recognition using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

I have a project where I need to identify the license plate of a car using OpenCV.

I want to load an image of a number or a letter and let OpenCV identify it and print it to the console.

Is there a function do this? If not, how can I do it?

**Note:** I am working on gray level

Please help, I have to make it a week from now

---

thank you for your fast answer

I am working with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition

and about library the following libraries are whwat i used:

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\lib"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cv\include"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cxcore\include"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\otherlibs\highgui"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cvaux\include"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\otherlibs\_graphics\include"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cv\src"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cxcore\src"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cvaux\src"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\otherlibs\highgui"
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\otherlibs\_graphics\src"
```

Comment: http://www.dtksoft.com/dtkanpr.php

Comment: You realise, that if you don't know how to do it a week won't be enough time, do you? Unless of course your problem is simpler than it seems.

Answer (score 3):

dunno what implementations are available in opencv, but a couple other libraries are:

- [JavaANPR](http://javaanpr.sourceforge.net/)
- [DTK ANPR](http://www.dtksoft.com/dtkanpr.php)

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking to learn more about OpenCV generally, you a good place to start is with this book: [*Learning OpenCV*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) by Bradksi et al.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been working on a simple implementation of ANPR in OpenCV python. You can check it out [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/kislayabhi/89b985e5b78a6f56029a)

It is written with the help of Shogun Machine Learning toolbox with the Image processing part in OpenCV. Do play with the variables as they need some tweaking for cars from different regions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the color of the ROI to create the filter. This will work until the plate region and the vehicle has the same color.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```