# Image Recognition API for Non-Faces

Tags: image, image-recognition

Does there exist a freely-accessible API for recognizing non-faces? Or is there a way to use the faces.detect call on the face.com API for non-faces?

I'd like something that could recognize what state a picture of a license plate was from.

Comment: Seems a platform/language tag is missing

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has a [general purpose object detector](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/objdetect__object_detection.html) which can be trained with Haar cascades. This is generalization to object detection of Viola & Jones' seminal approach for fast and accurate face detection.

For a tutorial on training the Haar classifier, see [this](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html). The link shows training for face recognition but you can use a similar process for any project (coming up with positive/negative examples, building up invariances, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at OpenCV or other libraries for computer vision... there have been many questions about license plate recognition here on StackOverflow:

[License plate recognition using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971582/license-plate-recognition-using-opencv)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048130/license-plate-recognition

[License Plate recognition using AForge.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556869/license-plate-recognition-using-aforge-net)

I am sure you can find something useful in there...

OpenCV offers quite a lot of tools for detection and segmentation.

Hope it helps...